# Where do Logrotate files end up?

Tags: logs, rsyslog, logrotate

I've got a Graylog server that I configured logrotating on.

```
/var/lib/graylog-server/journal/messagejournal-0/000*.log {
    size 2G
    create 550 ubuntu ubuntu
    rotate 5
}
```

I came in one morning and noticed the .log file was significantly smaller and the messages inside were from today - it had been rotated. I can't find where the rotate files went, though. Where do they end up, usually?

Edit:
I took a look for an xml file and found this one.

Edit:
I found the logging section in the server.conf; but It seems like it just gives you the option to set the size at which it creates a new index. It certainly doesn't seem as specific as logrotate. Is there any way to reconcile the two?

Comment: rotated logfiles are supposed to be in the same directory as the log file.  Check your logrotate.conf file to see how its configured

Comment: Graylog uses it's own log rotation configured in xml format and so check /etc/graylog/server